# SQL server 08 incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, excel, vba, syntax-error

Trying to insert the following values into a sql database from an excel macro

I get the following error message 'Incorrect Syntax near '('.

The code is...

```
Dim insert2 As String

insert2 = "INSERT INTO DETAIL" _
   & " ( plant, taskno, commentno, commentby, commenton, comment, nextactionby)   VALUES " _
   & " ( 'UK' ((SELECT max(taskno) AS count from HEADER),'1', '" & UserID & "', CONVERT(datetime, '" & Hdate & "' ,103), '" & Dcomment & "', '" & Dnextactionby & "')"
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Missing comma (,) after the word 'UK' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing comma and some unbalanced parentheses here:

```
'UK' ((SELECT max(taskno) AS count from HEADER)
   ^ ^^                                       ^
```

Comment: And a missing comma, I think.